# Is it possible for a PHP file to delete itself on execution?

Tags: php

I have a PHP file "**install.php**" which handles the installation of other scripts. I want this file to delete itself and its containing folder after it has been run.

Is this possible?

Comment: **Try It And See!!** I can even give you a comprehensive code: `<?php unlink(__FILE__);` so all you need to do is just copy-paste and run

Comment: hrm...good question. if the file were loaded into memory first, i don't see why not, but i'm really not sure. why don't you just try it?

Comment: Thanks, but how would I delete the folder containing the file? And is this a safe way? or do you guys use some other method in this situation?

Comment: `rmdir()` and `header()`. And yes, it is not necessary to read documentation if it is SO with thousands of people ready to answer!

Comment: @Christian Lavie: not for the questions like this. To check if php script can delete itself you would spent 1 minute to write 1 line

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A demo given that the folder only contains your install.php:

```
mkdir demo
cd demo
echo "<?php unlink(__FILE__); rmdir(__DIR__); " > install.php
php install.php
cd ..
ls
```

The that `ls` doesn't show the "demo dir" any more.

The recursive deletion shouldn't be that hard to figure out ether if there are more (sub-)folders you want to remove.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP [unlink](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) and [rmdir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php) command to delete the file (and its folder) itself. Make sure you forward the viewer to other page after you delete the file itself.