# PHP File rename itself

Tags: php, apache, upgrade, rename

I'm attempting to write an upgrade script for one of our website. Currently the script will unzip files provided from the upgrade link and unzip to the directory.

My problem is if there is a new version of itself i.e. `upgrader-new.php` I need the script to run to completion and then delete itself, then have`upgrader-new.php` be renamed to `upgrader.php`.

The only solution I can think of would be to create a third file i.e. `upgrade-assist.php` that would be run before any upgrade to check if `upgrader-new.php` exists and if it does, delete the original and rename the new to the proper name. I forsee problems because the original script would still have to call `upgrader-assist.php` and as far as I know you can't delete a running script?

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Consider a more robust system. Laravel's database migrations are individual files, with dates in their filenames so the system knows what order to apply them in. Allows things to be versioned and obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> as far as I know you can't delete a running script?

You can, try this one:

```
<?php unlink(__FILE__);
```

It is perfectly fine, unless there are other processes using this file (and of course running process has enough permission to do so).

File is not processed and executed line by line, but loaded into memory so you can freely rename or delete it, and it will still run until the end (or fatal error).

Comment: I appreciate the answer! Any suggestions as to rename the new script after the original has been deleted?

Comment: yes, you can!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242469/php-self-delete-file-is-it-possible   You just need to run the new PHP script (renamed one) and gracefully exit from the old one.

Comment: @SCHULTZ when file is deleted it does not mean that script associated with that file will stop - it is in the memory.

Comment: Well hot damn! I figured it would be locked in the filesystem. Thanks a bunch!